# Scrapy storing items across multiple formrequest pages? meta? python

Tags: python, global-variables, scrapy

So I got my scraper to work with one form request. I can even see the terminal prints out the scrape data as it goes from this single page version:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "swim"
    start_urls = ["example.website"]
    DOWNLAD_DELAY= 30.0

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,formname="TTForm",
                    formdata={"Ctype":"A", "Req_Team": "", "AgeGrp": "0-6", 
                    "lowage": "", "highage": "", "sex": "W", "StrkDist": "10025", 
                    "How_Many": "50", "foolOldPerl": ""}
                    ,callback=self.swimparse1,dont_click=True)]

    def swimparse1(self, response):       
        open_in_browser(response)
        hxs = Selector(response)
        rows = hxs.xpath(".//tr")
        items = []

        for rows in rows[4:54]:
            item = swimItem()
            item["names"] = rows.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").extract()
            item["age"] = rows.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").extract()
            item["free"] = rows.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").extract()
            item["team"] = rows.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

However, when I add in a second formrequest call back, it only scrapes the items in the second one. It also only prints the scrape from the second page, as if it completely skips the first page scrape? :

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "swim"
    start_urls = ["example.website"]
    DOWNLAD_DELAY= 30.0

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,formname="TTForm",
                    formdata={"Ctype":"A", "Req_Team": "", "AgeGrp": "0-6", 
                    "lowage": "", "highage": "", "sex": "W", "StrkDist": "10025", 
                    "How_Many": "50", "foolOldPerl": ""}
                    ,callback=self.swimparse1,dont_click=True)]

    def swimparse1(self, response):       
        open_in_browser(response)
        hxs = Selector(response)
        rows = hxs.xpath(".//tr")
        items = []

        for rows in rows[4:54]:
            item = swimItem()
            item["names"] = rows.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").extract()
            item["age"] = rows.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").extract()
            item["free"] = rows.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").extract()
            item["team"] = rows.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
            #print item[]           
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,formname="TTForm",
                    formdata={"Ctype":"A", "Req_Team": "", "AgeGrp": "0-6", 
                    "lowage": "", "highage": "", "sex": "W", "StrkDist": "40025", 
                    "How_Many": "50", "foolOldPerl": ""}
                    ,callback=self.Swimparse2,dont_click=True),]

    def swimparse2(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        hxs = Selector(response)
        rows = hxs.xpath(".//tr")
        items = []

        for rows in rows[4:54]:
            item = swimItem()
            item["names"] = rows.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").extract()
            item["age"] = rows.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").extract()
            item["fly"] = rows.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").extract()
            item["team"] = rows.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
            #print item[]
        return items
```

Guesses: 
A) How can I export or return the items from the first scrape into the second scrape so that I end up with all of the item data together as if it were scraped from one page?

B) Or in the event the first scrape is being completely skipped, how can I stop skipping and pass these items along to the next?

Thank you!

PS: additionally: I've tried using:

```
item = response.request.meta = ["item]
item = response.request.meta = []
item = response.request.meta = ["names":item, "age":item, "free":item, "team":item]
```

all of which create a key error or other exception raised

Ive also tried modifying the form request to include a meta={"names":item, "age":item, "free":item, "team":item}. doesnt raise errors, but doesnt scrape or store anything.

EDIT: I tried using yields like so:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "swim"
start_urls = ["www.website.com"]
DOWNLAD_DELAY= 30.0

def parse(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)
    hxs = Selector(response)
    rows = hxs.xpath(".//tr")
    items = []

    for rows in rows[4:54]:
        item = swimItem()
        item["names"] = rows.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").extract()
        item["age"] = rows.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").extract()
        item["free"] = rows.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").extract()
        item["team"] = rows.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").extract()
        items.append(item) 
        yield [FormRequest.from_response(response,formname="TTForm",
                formdata={"Ctype":"A", "Req_Team": "", "AgeGrp": "0-6", 
                "lowage": "", "highage": "", "sex": "W", "StrkDist": "10025", 
                "How_Many": "50", "foolOldPerl": ""}
                ,callback=self.parse,dont_click=True)]

    for rows in rows[4:54]:
        item = swimItem()
        item["names"] = rows.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").extract()
        item["age"] = rows.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").extract()
        item["fly"] = rows.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").extract()
        item["team"] = rows.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)

        yield [FormRequest.from_response(response,formname="TTForm",
                formdata={"Ctype":"A", "Req_Team": "", "AgeGrp": "0-6", 
                "lowage": "", "highage": "", "sex": "W", "StrkDist": "40025", 
                "How_Many": "50", "foolOldPerl": ""}
                ,callback=self.parse,dont_click=True)]
```

still is not scraping anything. I know that the xpaths are correct as when I only tried and scraped one form (with returns rather than yields) it works perfectly. I've read the scrappy documentation and it just is not very helpful :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing a very simple solution, change `return` to `yield`

you then dont have to accumulate items in an array, just yield as many items and requests as you want from your functions, scrapy will do the rest

from [scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html):

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from myproject.items import MyItem

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1.html',
        'http://www.example.com/2.html',
        'http://www.example.com/3.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        for h3 in sel.xpath('//h3').extract():
            yield MyItem(title=h3)

        for url in sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. unfortunately, yield doesnt seem to be helping. for debugging purposes I included an open browser command at each part of the code. with the yield in place of the first return only, the code stall (no browsers open) and I get this: ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list' in <POST http://website.com>. with the yield in place of any combination of the next two returns, the browsers open (the code executes?), but no scraping happens.

Comment: okay so the above comment I merely replaced return with yield. THIS time, I further indented the yields so that they would execute for every instance of the "for". However, still no scraping, and this error was printed probably as many times as the "for..." ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list' in <POST http://wwwwebtsite.cgi>

Comment: Im not sure how to show that this is the way to go :) I only write yields in my spiders and they always work, make sure you are don't yield None by printing the item before you yield it. and make sure you change **all** returns to yields

Comment: see an example on scrapy documentation http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html see how `MySpider` yields items and requests

Comment: thanks Guy. I edited my post with my attempt at yields... still not working, but thank you.

Comment: seems like you still not yielding items... you dont need item=[] and not items.append, instead just write `yield item`

Comment: I ended up going with a different solution, but I want to thank you for trying to help (selected your answer).